# Nexus (proxy)Repository Connection pending on remote storage And 404 on repository acces

Tags: proxy, npm, nexus

I have set up a sonatype **Nexus 3.0.0-03**. And trying to configure proxy repositories.

**Problems**:

- the created repositories are not accessible. `404` If I just open repository `URL`.
- The status in the repositories overview is on `Online - Remote Connection Pending...`

**Type** and **Format** of repository I have setup:

- proxy, npm
- proxy, nuget
- proxy, maven

**The goal** is proxy the remote Nexus npm repository and use it as a npm registry.

Additional information:

- I have no access to the settings of the remote Nexus, but as far as I understood this is not even necessary.
- Accessing the remote repository with npm is possible.
- I have already tried using npm install on created repository and it does not work. My Nexus is not fetching from remote Nexus' repository.

Answer (score 2):

**Solved** by correcting the **proxy settings**.
Host was not reachable, because the companies Nexus is not reachable from outside of companies network, but inside of companies network.

I had to change `no_proxy` and `NO_PROXY` environment variables from `*.company.com` to `.company.com`

*.company.com won't work for `nexus.company.com`